# What happens if the user selects American English but I only provide "English"?

Tags: iphone, internationalization

For example: I have an `en.lproj` subdirectory in my application bundle which contains all `English` content.

Now, Apple says that users can choose not only a language, but also some kind of dialect too. So we may have here "American English" or "British English". The user might choose American English, and then what happens next?

Like I understand, the System would look for an `en_US.lproj` subdirectory.   Is it clever enough to then see: "Oh no, there is no `en_US.lproj`, but there is an `en.lproj`"?  Or would it be dumb as bread and select `fr.lproj` or `de.lproj`?

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions:

- Set "en" as default developpement language (in your Info.plist),
- Copy en.lproj directory to en_US.lproj directory each time you make a distribution build (if your default language is not english).

But maybe after "en_US", the system looks for "en". I don't know..

Answer (score 1):

According to the "hints" in the [Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW23) (and also common sense) I would assume that it will fallback form "en_US" to "en" (the documentation says, that the region `_US` is optional.

However I remember some posts in the apple dev forums, that "en" is preferred over "en_US" if existent. But I might have got that wrong.